# How to get current month?

Tags: excel, vba

I can't get the current month.

It seems very simple to get the current year and day, as tested with the following:

```
MsgBox Year(Date)
MsgBox Day(Date)
MsgBox Year(Now)
MsgBox Day(Now)
```

How is it possible to show the current month as either a number (1, 2 etc.) or a full name?

I could use `TODAY()` in a cell and convert that in VBA with something like `CurrentMonth = MonthName(Month(Sheet1.Range("A1")))` but I would like to do this directly in VBA for Excel.

Comment: `Month(Now)` doesn't work?  It should return 3

Comment: No it doesn't for some reason, hence my confusion.

Comment: `?month(date), month(now)` will return `3, 3` - what do you see?

Comment: Interesting, as it works for me.  I put `? Month(Now)` in the immediate window and it returned 3 for me.  You could try `MsgBox Application.Evaluate ("MONTH(TODAY())")`

Comment: I get `Compile Error: Expected Array` when trying to run through.

Comment: @TimWilkinson you probably use some reserved words like "date" as field name or variable. First solve your compilation issue.

Comment: You've declared a variable/routine called Month somewhere.

Comment: Got the Friday vibe on a Thursday, I was declaring Month as a string further up the script. Works as it should now.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try,

```
debug.print Format(Date, "mmm")       'Mar
debug.print Format(Date, "mmmm")      'March
debug.print Format(Date, "m")    '3
debug.print Format(Date, "mm")   '03
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 Month(Now)
```

Returns the index number associated with the current month.

Jeeped's code below is the most compact, but to give you an idea of how indexes work, the following code will return the month name based on the index returned:

```
Dim months(11) As String
months(0) = "Jan"
months(1) = "Feb"
months(2) = "Mar"
months(3) = "Apr"
months(4) = "May"
months(5) = "Jun"
months(6) = "Jul"
months(7) = "Aug"
months(8) = "Sep"
months(9) = "Oct"
months(10) = "Nov"
months(11) = "Dec"

Dim nowMonth As Integer
nowMonth = Month(Now)

For i = 0 To 11
  If nowMonth = (i + 1) Then
     MsgBox (months(i))
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 6):

Found an easier solution to get the current Month Name

Just use `MonthName(Month(Now))` and assign it to a string.

`Month(Now)` gives you the month number and `MonthName()` uses that number to display the current month

Answer (score 3):

A really helpful and simple way is to combine the format function together with date.

Examples (assuming today is Oct 23, 2019):

To get current month as a number as in original question:

```
MsgBox Format(Date, "mm")
```

^ Will return: 10

To get current month as short text:

```
MsgBox Format(Date, "mmm")
```

^ Will return: Oct

To get current month with full text:

```
MsgBox Format(Date, "mmmm")
```

^ Will return: October

You can combine these with days and years as well.

Additional examples:

```
MsgBox Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

^ Will return 23-Oct-2019

```
MsgBox Format(Date, "dddd-mmmm-dd-yyyy")
```

^ Will return: Wednesday-October-23-2019

This is creating a custom format, so you can rearrange the dd, mm, yyyy areas as you see fit, such as:

```
MsgBox Format(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd")
```

^ Will return: 2019/23/10

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way I have found to do it:

```
Sub getMonth()

'MsgBox DatePart("m", Date)
'MsgBox Evaluate("MONTH(""" & Date & """)")
'MsgBox VBA.DateTime.Month(Date)

MsgBox Format(Date, "mmmm")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I found the previous month based on the current month name, the assignment to monthNum is the piece needed to solve your question.

```
month = "February"
'****'
  monthNum = Application.Evaluate("=MONTH(1&" & Chr(34) & month & Chr(34) & ")") 'Returns month #
'****'
If monthNum = 1 Then
    monthNum = 12
Else
    monthNum = monthNum - 1
End If
month = MonthName(monthNum) 'Returns January
```